# Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject EROR

Tags: java, json

I keep receiving the above error whenever I try to save my user input data to sql database. This is my fist app for transferring data to SQL and I am very very badly stuck here and its the only error I get.

Below is my JSONParser,java

```
       import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStream;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
       import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
       import java.util.List;
       import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
       import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
       import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
       import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
       import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
       import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
       import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
       import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
       import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
       import org.json.JSONException;
       import org.json.JSONObject;
        import android.util.Log;



         public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are getting back JSON from the server.

Comment: so how do I solve that??

Comment: You figure out what your server is sending you and you parse it _appropriately_. Also, read [how do I compare strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).